# Converting a MATLAB quadgk integration to Scipy quad with a long function to integrate (any alternative to passing a lambda function?)

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, numerical-integration

Okay I have this MATLAB code which passes into the `integrand` function the values for x generated by `quadgk` during its integration:

```
optionvalue(i) = exp(-r .* T2) .* quadgk(@(x) integrand(x,flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1), 0, Inf, 'AbsTol',tolerance);

function value = integrand(x, flag, F,K,vol,T2,T1)
d1 = (log(x ./ (x+K)) + 0.5 .* (vol.^2) .* (T2-T1)) ./ (vol .* sqrt(T2 - T1));
d2 = d1 - vol.*sqrt(T2 - T1);
mu = log(F) - 0.5 .*vol .^2 .* T1;
sigma = vol .* sqrt(T1);
value = lognpdf(x, mu, sigma) .* (flag .* x.*normcdf(flag .* d1) - flag .* (x+K).*normcdf(flag .* d2));
```

So now I go over to SciPy trying to replicate the above and I get stuck on passing the values for `x`.  SciPy shows that the function `quad` has to take a lambda function - how the heck can I put that long `integrand` function into that format (or some other way to make it work)?  Almost like I have to rewrite it as a `f(x)` type and remove the `x` variable passing into the function itself.  Here's what I have for Python so far:

```
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm

# Define function and interval

def integrand(x, flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1):
    d1 = (np.log(x / (x+K)) + 0.5 * (vol**2) * (T2-T1)) / (vol * np.sqrt(T2 - T1))
    d2 = d1 - vol*np.sqrt(T2 - T1)
    mu = np.log(F) - 0.5 *vol **2 * T1
    sigma = vol * np.sqrt(T1)
    return lognorm.pdf(x, mu, sigma) * (flag * x*norm.cdf(flag * d1) - flag * (x+K)*norm.cdf(flag * d2))

 quad, quad_err = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.Inf, args=(x, flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1))
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way easier than I thought to run this function, just omit the `x` variable in Python when calling `quad` and it will pass it automatically in its routine. I.e.

```
args=(flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1))
```

It assumes the `x` input variable in the:

```
def integrand(x, flag, F, K, vol, T2, T1):
```

Statement without you passing that argument in through `args=()`

Comment: Although use Python `lognorm.pdf(x, scale=np.exp(mu), s=sigma)` to be equivalent to MATLAB's `lognpdf(x, mu, sigma)` if you're looking to copy / paste my code between the 2 languages as I've tied it out to be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2):

> SciPy shows that the function quad has to take a lambda function - how the heck can I put that long integrand function into that format (or some other way to make it work)?

I wish we wouldn't call them lambda functions -- it makes it seem like there's something special about the result of using the `lambda` syntax, when there's not, really.

`quad` accepts a *function* -- it doesn't matter which syntax you used to construct it.

```
>>> def f(x): return x**2
>>> quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
0.3333333333333333
>>> quad(lambda x: x**2, 0, 1)[0]
0.3333333333333333
>>> g = lambda x: x**2 # no point to naming this, but anyway
>>> quad(g, 0, 1)[0]
0.3333333333333333
```

or, maybe more like your situation,

```
>>> def h(x, a): return (x+a)**2
>>> quad(h, 0, 1, args=5)[0]
30.33333333333333
>>> quad(lambda x: (x+5)**2, 0, 1)[0]
30.33333333333333
```

Comment: Thanks I think I just figured this one out - the question came from longer functions.  It seems all I had to do was omit the `x`  from `args=`when calling `quad` and everything works....